# Where did the money in the safe deposit come from

Tags: plot-explanation, framed

The question is about the $250k in the safe deposit box in the 1947 movie *Framed*.

I assumed as the bank VP, Steven Price stole it from the bank. Now, I've read the money was stolen/embezzled from Price's wealthy wife's bank account.

That makes more sense in the context of the movie.

Obviously, I missed that detail. Can anyone tell me where the reference shows up in the movie?